# Xpath: pass an 'include everything' parameter to [starts-with(...)]

Tags: regex, xml, xslt, xpath, wildcard

Using Saxon HE/Xpath 2

To filter my xml file of a list of businesses by 'BusinessType' I pass a parameter (ie "Restaurant" or "School") to the xsl file:

```
"java.exe" -jar "saxon9he.jar" -s:FHRS.xml -xsl:FHRS.xsl BusinessType="Restaurant"
```

The BusinessType category names are quite long so to save typing I pass the parameter to `starts-with`:

```
<xsl:param name="BusinessType"/>
<xsl:variable name="ID_New" select="//Details[starts-with(BusinessType,$BusinessType)]/FHRSID"/>
```

This is just a one line example. The same format is used multiple times in the xsl routine.

Is it possible to pass an 'return everything' wildcard parameter to $BusinessType? I've tried `*` and `.*`. I'm not well versed in RegEx.

Comment: `starts-with` does not work at all with regular expressions. It is currently not clear what you want to achieve, whether you want to return all `Details` elements if you don't set the parameter or whether you want to match a certain pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `starts-with` function https://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-starts-with works only with strings, not with regular expressions. However an empty sequence or an empty string as the second argument means the function returns true so you could simply define `<xsl:param name="BusinessType" select="()"/>` and then, if you don't want to filter, you don't set the parameter and the predicate `starts-with(BusinessType,$BusinessType)` is always true.

If you want to use regular expressions you need to use the `matches` function e.g. `matches(BusinessType,$BusinessType)` where a pattern to match any starting character would be if you set the param to `^.*`.

Comment: In other words, try `"java.exe" ... BusinessType=""` as your command line. Because every string starts with `""`.

Comment: Just tried BusinessType="" & works as I wanted. I didn't realise select option could be empty. 
Looking further inot it some other sites are using select="''". Is there any difference?